# Display Age automatically when birthdate is filled MVC 3 Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, attributes

In my Add Form I have a textbox for BIRTHDATE and AGE. I want that the textbox of the AGE will get the value in the textbox of BIRTHDATE - DateTime.Now and Display it instantly.

Can I do this in my model class like the compare attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do the calculation client-side in JavaScript, or server-side and then access that via an Ajax call.

This is a piece of JavaScript I found:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function Age()
{
var bday=parseInt(document.forms[0].txtBday.value);
var bmo=(parseInt(document.forms[0].txtBmo.value)-1);
var byr=parseInt(document.forms[0].txtByr.value);
var byr;
var age;
var now = new Date();
tday=now.getDate();
tmo=(now.getMonth());
tyr=(now.getFullYear());

{
if((tmo > bmo)||(tmo==bmo & tday>=bday))
{age=byr}

else
{age=byr+1}
alert("As of today, "+now+' \n'+", you are:"+(tyr-age)+ " years old");
}}
//-->
</script>
```

if you're going for the Ajax solution, you can make an easy Ajax call to an MVC action method using the jQuery `$.ajax` method.